# Monaca で appC Cloud プラグイン利用時、課金権限が ON になる

Tags: android, monaca, cordova, アプリ内課金

Monaca で Andorid アプリをビルドするときに appC Cloud プラグインを ON にすると課金機能を利用していなくても `com.android.vending.BILLING` 権限が ON になってしまうようなのですが、これを回避する方法はありますか？

Google Play ストアでも課金機能がないのに 「アプリ内購入あり」 と表示されてしまいます。課金なしの無料アプリとして表示された状態で appC Cloud 広告を入れたいです。

Monaca の以前のバージョンでは `AndroidManifest.xml` が手動で設定できていたかと思うのですが、今は自動で作成されてしまうようです。

Answer (score 1):

調べてみたところ、appC Cloudプラグインのplugin.xmlの中でcom.android.vending.BILLINGをで宣言しているようです。appC Cloudのこのplugin.xmlはMonaca IDE上からは編集できないので、課金権限をOFFにするのは難しいと思います。